# R shiny Dashboard : Exceed the bootstrap width = 12 and add an horizontal scrollbar

Tags: r, shiny, bootstrap-4, shinydashboard

I'm currently learning to use R shiny dashboard. I'm using fluidrow(column(...)) to do my page layout.
I'm currently facing a problem: I can't put as much elements as I would like in a row. Basically, I would like to put a lot of elements on the same line with an horizontal scrollbar.

example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem("My Tab", tabName = "my_Tab", icon = icon("th"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "my_Tab",
            fluidRow(
              column(width = 2,
                     numericInput("n1", "N", value = 1, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1)
              ),
              column(width = 2,
                     numericInput("n2", "N", value = 1, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1)
              ),
              column(width = 2,
                     numericInput("n3", "N", value = 1, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1)
              ),
              column(width = 2,
                     numericInput("n4", "N", value = 1, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1)
              ),
              column(width = 2,
                     numericInput("n5", "N", value = 1, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1)
              ),
              column(width = 2,
                     numericInput("n6", "N", value = 1, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1)
              ),
              column(width = 2,
                     numericInput("n7", "N", value = 1, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1)
              )
            )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here, the last numeric input is not display next to the n6 numeric input. Does anyone knows how to solve my problem ? 
I did not find any solution on the internet even though I'm pretty sure it is not that hard.

Thank you !

Comment: I would like to add that it seems I am forced to use column. If I don't, elements are put in different line. It is strange because it's not the same behavior as in this tuto: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#row-based-layout
For example, take my code and remove every "column()" function.

Comment: In Shiny dashboard total width is 12. you have given column width as 2. hence 6 column can be max fitted in same row.You can change to 1 to fit total 12 column.But remember under column if you put any box or plot or any other object you need to tweak the things in there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if I change width to 1, the elements are too small. Is there a way to say : "width=1 but also width=100px" for example ? And it would force a scrollbar to appear.
I'm not sur I understand what you mean by "tweak the things"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole idea of the bootstrap layout is that elements resize and reflow to new rows. So I would suggest using custom `CSS` in this particular case rather than relying on bootstrap's `fluidRow` and `column`.

1. Add a horizontal scroll-bar using `overflow-x`

   - Use `div` as a placeholder with the same role as `fluidRow`.
   - `overflow-x: scroll;` sets a horizontal bar that is visible only when there are more elements that fit the width.
2. Add `CSS` in `dashboardBody`

   - Create a new CSS class called `same-row`

     - Control the `max-width` if you want smaller elements
     - `display: table-cell;` forces the elements to stay in a single row
     - Use `padding-right` to get some space between elements
3. Change `column` to `div` that uses the previously defined `same-row` class.

*Optional*: Instead of copy-pasting create the elements with `lapply`

#### Full code:

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
      .same-row {
        max-width: 200px;
        display: table-cell;
        padding-right: 10px;
      }
    '))),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "my_Tab",
            div(style = "overflow-x:scroll;",
              lapply(1:10, function(i) {
                div(class = "same-row",
                    numericInput(paste0("n", i), "N", value = 1, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1)
                )
              })
            )
    )
  )
)
```

Please note that there are other methods to place multiple elements in a single row, `table-cell` display is just one of them.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you !