# R Shiny layout of blocks, rows and headers

Tags: html, r, layout, shiny

I'm finalizing my R Shiny app and I am struggling with the layout of blocks and headers. Since I have a lot of blocks, I've built my layout separately and coded it in the ui of my Shiny app using a combination of fluidRow and column. Usually each of my block then has a title, under the form p(...), followed by some information under the same form.

Since I like the idea of having a "controls" side-bar panel, the blocks on the left side of my app are used to control the different inputs I use on the app. When the user does stuff, the blocks on the left side are the ones that are impacted and modified.

I have a full row blocks that belong to the same "category". It is a dynamic UI that can have 1 to 8 blocks depending on a slider input the user can play with. What I am trying to achieve is to have one title line (either a paragraph, or a header, doesn't matter) the line above the blocks, then have the blocks, while keeping only one unit on the "control panel" on the left side.

A few images to make it clearer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI0E3.jpg is what I currently have for most of my blocks. One line for title (blue), one line for content (green). Dark green is the general "row" and red are the "blocks". The code for this layout is the following:

```
fluidRow(
    column(4, wellPanel()),
    column(2, mainPanel(
        p("blue"),
        p("green")
    )),
    column(2, mainPanel()),
    column(2, mainPanel()),
    column(2, mainPanel())
)
```

Now, that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1QTh.jpg is what I am trying to achieve, and I have not been able to reach that result yet. I have tried a couple of things:

1) Using a different fluidRow for the title and for the contents. The problem with that is the formatting, since the control box on the left is part of the first row, it is constraining the height of the row itself, meaning the header will be much higher than the contents. It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzaaZ.jpg, and I want to cut down the useless space.

Syntax for that would be:

```
fluidRow(
    column(4, wellPanel()),
    column(8, mainPanel(
        p("blue")
    ))
),
fluidRow(
    column(4, mainPanel()),
    column(2, mainPanel(
        p("green")
    )),
    column(2, mainPanel()),
    column(2, mainPanel()),
    column(2, mainPanel())
)
```

2) Nestling the sub-blocks within a larger column. The code for that would be like this:

```
fluidRow(
    column(4, wellPanel()),
    column(8, mainPanel(
        p("blue"),
        column(2, mainPanel(
            p("green")
        )),
        column(2, mainPanel()),
        column(2, mainPanel()),
        column(2, mainPanel())
    ))
)
```

And the problem with that is that, somehow, columns within columns seem not to be behaving properly. Instead of having the width 2 columns occupying the whole space of my width 8 columns, they end up having a weird width and overlapping each other.

Ideas? There might be an easy HMTL solution but I'm really not an expert in that.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It it better to embed your images in your post instead of adding them as links. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the second column into four columns of width 3. Placing these columns inside `fluidRow` will also align them to the title element above.

---

**EDIT**

Dynamically generated columns and boxes. Set the width of the box as `ceiling(12 / number of boxes)`. When the sum of widths exceeds 12, the boxes overflow in second row. We have to use something like `ceiling` or `floor` because fractions are not allowed in the bootstrap system, and when `width` is, e.g., 1.5, the boxes inherit the width of the parent column. An option is to set the maximum box width to 3 and have a two-row layout when the user selects > 4 boxes.

[image]

---

Code:

```
library(shiny)

wp <- tagList(wellPanel(
  h3("Title"),
  p(
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  )
))

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  column(
    width = 4,
    wp,
    sliderInput(
      "n_boxes",
      label = "Number of boxes",
      min = 1,
      max = 8,
      value = 2,
      step = 1
    )
  ),
  column(width = 8,
         wellPanel(h2("T I T L E")),
         uiOutput("blocks"))
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  make_boxes <- reactive({
    box_width <- ceiling(12 / input$n_boxes)
    message(box_width)

    x <-
      lapply(1:input$n_boxes, function(x)
        column(width = box_width, wp))
    x
  })

  output$blocks <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(make_boxes())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For a potential alternative approach that allows with of the column to exceed 12 and uses a horizontal scrollbar, have a look at this thread: [R shiny Dashboard : Exceed the bootstrap width = 12 and add an horizontal scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647029/r-shiny-dashboard-exceed-the-bootstrap-width-12-and-add-an-horizontal-scroll)

Comment: Hi, thank for suggesting this solution. The header works great but the other content does not. I have a variable number of blocks under the header (1 to 8) so I cannot spend more than 1 width per unit. I was expecting to see something that would take the 2/3 of the page, but actually they use 1 unit space, regardless of whether they are nested in a sub fluidrow. Furthermore, when the number of units is maxed out at 8, the last one usually ends up on a new row (could be just a display bug).
Interestingly, on browser, the page keeps "resizing" in width, which makes it basically unreadable.

Comment: See if my edits get you closer. And also check out the alternative approach in the link.

Comment: This works. I am still getting some display glitch on the browser version of Shiny. It's very strange, like the page is "twitching", as if continuously trying to adjust its width but not knowing which width to settle for. I only have the issue at the 75% zoom level on Chrome, anything else is fine, which is very weird... I don't know exactly what is causing the issue. I'm not fully familiar with SO, should I green checkmark your answer now?

Comment: If you think my reply addresses your question, you can click the check mark to 'accept' the answer. But you can also wait for other members to reply with potentially better solutions. It is up to you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I think your answer is good enough (besides, you provided two different solutions). Thanks again!